# I am trying to break down break 1 column down into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split

I am writing mySQL view

The current column examples are;

```
001 London (UK)
002 Manchester (UK)
003 New York (USA)
```

I am trying to display in a separate column;

```
001 UK
002 UK
003 USA
```

basically drop the city & brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses string functions:

```
select 
    substring_index(col, ' ', 1) val1,
    substring(substring_index(col, ')', 1), locate('(', col) + 1) val2
from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d88eb73aa8c3df48ca98ada145932f6)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^.*[()]([^)]*)[)]$', '$1')
```